# Nhibernate inserting with values on a bag

Tags: nhibernate

I am using a where clause on a bag to filter a bag. Is there any way to make nhibernate insert these filter values into the database?

Comment: What's in this bag? primitive values? References? composite-elements? Where do you want to insert it?

Comment: the bag contains a many to many relationship. I am using one table as the joining table and need to set bool values so that each bag pulls back the correct references.

Comment: I don't understand "set bool values so that each bag pulls back the correct references".

Comment: I think I start to understand, you have the same table for two many-to-many relations. Is this a legacy database? How do you want to fix it by "inserting these filter values into the database"?

Comment: Sorry my explanation probably wasn't great. Its not legacy but I just thought it would be better to use the one table instead of 4. 

I just need when an insert in performed on the bag that it insert two booleans as default with sepcified values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, it is not worth trying to share a table between many-to-many relations. You can't access the boolean flags in this tables, so you can't change it from NH, except using native sql, which is not how NHibernate should be used. And it will be very very very complicated to make changes on these bags. These table is completely invisible for the object oriented point of view and completely managed by NH.

Just map it to different tables and you'll be happy. Believe me.